# Scrolldown not working on iPad

Tags: html, css

Would you know why I can't scroll down my page on an iPad? Here is [the link](http://goo.gl/tlBtVT) (would be too long to put the full CSS and HTML here). That must be something in my CSS code but can't figure out what exactly.
Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a javascript issue, if i turn js off on my ipad, it works.

I have a feeling it's

skrollr.min.js

Edit: https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr/issues/265 might be useful